# How to create a new project from an exisiting project in Texas Instruments Code Composer?

Tags: c, msp430, code-composer

I would like to archive a finished version of a C program for the MSP430, programmed using TI Code Composer Studio version 5.2.1, creating a new project for a new version I’m going to add new features to.

Attempts to follow TI's documentation and using File/Import, File/Export, and Project/Import Existing CCS Eclipse Project resulted in messy results, with nothing resulting in anything that matched the source project under a new project name.

I simply want to copy a project, give the copy of the project a new name, and move on, retaining the project settings and source code files in the original project. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your using CCS5

```
copy the source project (select it and Ctrl+C)

paste it (Ctrl+V)

The `Copy Project` dialog allows you to rename the copy.

Everything is copied: subfolders, links, includes, processor options, all the details that a manual approach could miss.
```